# How to recursive list files with size and last modified time?

Tags: linux, bash

Given a directory i'm looking for a bash one-liner to get a recursive list of all files with their size and modified time tab separated for easy parsing. Something like:

```
cows/betsy       145700    2011-03-02 08:27
horses/silver    109895    2011-06-04 17:43
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`stat(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) to get the information you want, if you don't want the full `ls -l` output, and you can use [`find(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to get a recursive directory listing.  Combining them into one line, you could do this:

```
# Find all regular files under the current directory and print out their
# filenames, sizes, and last modified times
find . -type f -exec stat -f '%N %z %Sm' '{}' +
```

If you want to make the output more parseable, you can use `%m` instead of `%Sm` to get the last modified time as a `time_t` instead of as a human-readable date.

Answer (score 6):

find is perfect for recursively searching through directories. The `-ls` action tells it to output its results in `ls -l` format:

```
find /dir/ -ls
```

On Linux machines you can print customized output using the `-printf` action:

```
find /dir/ -printf '%p\t%s\t%t\n'
```

See `man find` for full details on the format specifiers available with `-printf`. (This is not POSIX-compatible and may not be available on other UNIX flavors.)

Comment: The `-printf` primary is not POSIX; some `find` implementations (in particular, that of Mac OS X) do not include it.

Answer (score 2):

`find * -type f -printf '%p\t%s\t%TY-%Tm-%Td %Tk:%TM\n'`

If you prefer fixed-width fields rather than tabs, you can do things like changing `%s` to `%10s`.

I used `find * ...` to avoid the leading "./" on each file name.  If you don't mind that, use `.` rather than `*` (which also shows files whose names start with `.`).  You can also pipe the output through `sed 's/^\.\///'`.

Note that the output order will be arbitrary.  Pipe through `sort` if you want an ordered listing.

Comment: The `-printf` primary is not POSIX; some `find` implementations (in particular, that of Mac OS X) do not include it.

Comment: @Adam: Good point.  (Of course you can install GNU findutils on MacOS, but that might not be practical or worth the effort.)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this for recursive listing from current folder called "/from_dir"

```
find /from_dir/* -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c “%n|%A|%a|%U|%G” > permissions_list.txt
```

Lists files and directories passes through to stat command and puts all the info into a file called permissions_list.txt

“%n|%A|%a|%U|%G” will give you the following result in the file:

```
from_     dir|drwxr-sr-x|2755|root|root     
from_dir/filename|-rw-r–r–|644|root|root
```

Cheers!